# Creating barchart in android

Tags: android, web-services, bar-chart

Has any one met this issue.Right now i am trying to show a bar-chart in android,but i am getting the x and y axis values from the web service by consuming it.I am consuming it by the method SOAP.Here i am getting this issues,can anyone tell me how to overcome this issue?

**LOGCAT**

```
09-17 10:18:09.651: W/KeyCharacterMap(339): No keyboard for id 0
09-17 10:18:09.651: W/KeyCharacterMap(339): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
09-17 10:18:20.450: D/AndroidRuntime(339): Shutting down VM
09-17 10:18:20.450: W/dalvikvm(339): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.xmlparsing_test/com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity.buildBarDataset(BarGraphActivity.java:120)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity.DrawGraph(BarGraphActivity.java:61)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.example.xmlparsing_test.BarGraphActivity.onCreate(BarGraphActivity.java:26)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-17 10:18:20.460: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  ... 11 more
```

BarGraphActivity.java

```
 public class BarGraphActivity extends Chart
 {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    Chart ch = new Chart();
    DrawGraph();
}

public void DrawGraph() 
{
String[] titles = new String[] { " Barcharts",""};

double[] x_axis = null;   
double[] y_axis = null;

List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();

values.add(x_axis);
values.add(y_axis);

int[] colors = new int[] { Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK};

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

setChartSettings(renderer, "some texts", " ", " ",0,x_axis, 0,y_axis, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
renderer.setXLabels(1);

renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "x_axis");
renderer.addYTextLabel(1, "y_axis");

renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);

int length = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
  SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i);
  seriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
  }

ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer,Type.DEFAULT);
}

protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) 
{

        // creates a SeriesRenderer and initializes it with useful default values as well as colors

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(15);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);

    int length = colors.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
      SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
      r.setColor(colors[i]);
      renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
    return renderer;
  }

protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String title, String xTitle,
String yTitle, double xMin, double[] x_axis, double yMin, double[] y_axis, int axesColor,int labelsColor) 
 {
    // sets lots of default values for this renderer

renderer.setChartTitle(title);

renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);

renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);

renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);

renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}

protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> values) 
{
        // adds the axis titles and values into the dataset

XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

int length = titles.length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
   CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);

   double[] v = values.get(i);

   int seriesLength = v.length;

   for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) 
   {
     series.add(v[k]);
    }

   dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
   }
return dataset;
 }    }
```

Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: there is a error in the at BarGraphActivity class and in the  buildBarDataset method

Comment: @GoogleResearcher i've given BarGraphActivity.java for reference on the above question,can you tell what mistake i am committing here?

Comment: friend can you post your 120th line your bar activity class

Comment: @GoogleResearcher actually the 120th line is just a blank space,so i will provide you the next line,                                          for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++)

Comment: the error was it was unable to load List<double[]> values or there is no content stored in List<double[]>values

Answer (score 0):

There are Other Ways to make Graph do u need this method only or do u want any other .? 
if yes i will Edit my answer with a new `Bar Graph Activity`